# InitialDirectory для FileDialog

Tags: c#

Всем привет :)
Как можно добавить InitialDirectory для FileDialog в файл конфигурации XML?

Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, приведите пример желаемого поведения и как пытались реализовать, из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно

Comment: @yolosora у меня программа по добавлению текста в выбранный пользоваталем файл, я бы хотела, чтобы с помощью InitialDirectory открывалась уже определенная папка и путь к этой папке хотела бы хранить в файле конфиругации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, в App.config нужно добавить конфигурацию вида

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="path" value="C:\"></add>
</appSettings>
```

И используйте ее в коде

```
var fd = new OpenFileDialog {InitialDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"],RestoreDirectory = false};
fd.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ :)